# Firebase Realtime Database Rule - Security Function

Tags: c#, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

In my database, I have the following structure.

/Players/UID{1,2,3,...n}/ for each UID ==> {Child1,Child2,...Childn}

In the rules, in order to secure the data, I created a function between the childs similar to below, however, the write operations task is faulted and I do not know the reason. In addition, can you propose something more secure and practical to implement?

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null && newData.child('Child1').val() * newData.child('Child1').val() * 1000000 + 1000 * newData.child('Child1').val() - 1000 === newData.child('Child2').val()"
  }
}
```

My simplified write function is as below where Child2 is a function of Child1;

```
public void WriteDatabase(float child1, int child2)
    {
        if (AuthController.Instance != null && AuthController.Instance.user != null)
        {
            uid = AuthController.Instance.user.UserId;
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
        LeaderBoardEntry entry = new LeaderBoardEntry(child1, child2);

        Dictionary<string, System.Object> entryValues = entry.ToDictionary();
        Dictionary<string, System.Object> childUpdates = new Dictionary<string, System.Object>();
        childUpdates["/Players/" + uid + "/"] = entryValues;
        reference.UpdateChildrenAsync(childUpdates).ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            if (task.IsCanceled)
            {
                UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Write database cancelled");
                return;
            }

            if (task.IsFaulted)
            {
                UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Write database faulted");
                return;
            }

            if (task.IsCompleted)
            {
                UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Write database completed");
            }
        });
    }
```

Note: The write function works well with below rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the [minimal, compelte/standalone code that doesn't work the way you expect it to](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I edited, thnx for your comment.

Comment: We have no way to know what `child1` and `child2` are here. Please please please make sure that the code is both minimal, and complete, meaning we can run it standalone, without needing anything that is not present in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rules are set up to validate the data that is written to the root:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null && 
       newData.child('Child1').val() * newData.child('Child1').val() * 1000000 + 1000 * newData.child('Child1').val() - 1000
        === newData.child('Child2').val()"
  }
}
```

So this allows any authenticated user to write a value matching the specific formula to the root of the database.

But your code is writing the same structure to `/Players/$uid`, which is a different location in the database.

You'll need to make sure you define these validation rules in the right place in the database:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    "Players": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "auth != null && 
           newData.child('Child1').val() * newData.child('Child1').val() * 1000000 + 1000 * newData.child('Child1').val() - 1000
            === newData.child('Child2').val()"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for your help Frank, better representation of my database structure. After a lot of trials, I realized that, the error was Permission Denied due to the reason that, the floating variable is not recognized as number and the calculation does not work... I created another integer variable to check it and it works like a charm :)

Comment: In case I need, how can I get value of "1.002" as number in the rules to make calculations? .val() gets it as string I guess.

Comment: `.val()` gets the value of a node, in whatever it is stored in. If you've stored a number, it gets a number. I vaguely recall something about floating points numbers, but can't find something about it immediately. If you can reproduce the problem, I recommend opening a question with a [minimal, complete/standalone reproduction](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please makes sure to include the minimal, code, JSON, and rules, all in text form, to make it easiest for someone to reproduce from what you shared.